# Picture paramater in fb.api not showing

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have been trying to show the image on this test Facebook post but to no avail. Kindly check my code. The image/picture is existing as it is my avatar here.

```
function PostTest() {
    FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', {
        message: "This is the test message!",
        source: 'http://www.test.com',
        link: 'http://www.test.com',
        picture: 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/dd703fc997aba7a8a8abc60f2613e570?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1'
    }, function (response) {
        if (response && response.id) {
            alert('success');
        } else if (response && response.error && 200 == response.error.code) {
        alert('error');
        }
    });
}
```

This is the result after calling that.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) says that -

> The picture must be at least 200px by 200px.

and your picture is 128x128.

Hope that it will help. Good luck!

Comment: tried to do what you said, but still did not work. thanks anyway.

Comment: Can you give the url of the new pic?

Comment: http://scontent-a-ord.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-prn2/1456598_546242408797132_287450666_n.png

Comment: The picture is posted when i tried with Graph API Explorer. So pls try again.. http://imgur.com/wkVZfz5

Comment: I have also fixed it by adding a url property in the fb.api call. I set url and picture values as the same. Then it finally displays! :)